# Avoid chrome "pages unresponsive" upon javascript long execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, message

I have a javascript LONG execution procedure (and reasons to have it). How can I avoid *in javascript* the message on the client machines? I read something about 
--disable-hang-monitor, but is a command line argument or setting, not javascript (also, I read isnt working allways)

Comment: Do `async` and `defer` attributes on script tags solve the problem?

Comment: In most cases there should be no valid reasons to have such scripts. You say that you have "reasons", what are they? What is the code doing?

Comment: Thanks  Ali Sheikhpour for your comment. but neither async nor defer avoid the message when the scripts takes a long time.

Comment: Thanks  battlmonstr for your comment. (In short: A project to create software capable to write code business logic by itself), But please focus in help us -if you know how- with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are doing complex calculations that can't be broken down in smaller chunks, web workers seem to the solution to me.
It's the javascript mechanism to run code in a separate thread, but you have to communicate with that thread (called a worker) via messaging:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

```
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
first.onchange = function() {
  myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
  console.log('Message posted to worker');
}

second.onchange = function() {
  myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
  console.log('Message posted to worker');
}

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
  result.textContent = e.data;
  console.log('Message received from worker');
}
```

In the worker:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

Comment: I´ll try the monday. Thanks!

Comment: After a while I tested it, and it works as you say (no more anoying messages even with long process). I didnt try all the features yet, but the basis works, Now on my library. Thanks!